# print scale to some % like 50% by using CSS for IE9,10,11

Tags: html, css

Zoom css property not working for IE9,10,11.
Observed while print preview UI disturbing and the default scale is Shrink to fit.
When i changed this scale from Shrink to fit to 50% the page is displaying properly(print preview).Can any one help how can i set scale to 50% using CSS code.

Comment: Can you post the CSS code you already have?

Comment: Hi james, Thank you for your reply. For print just i used window.print() javascript function and it is perfectly working in Chrome. I didn't write any css code to print. Same thing is not working in IE(print preview).

Comment: I searched in google they suggested use zoom or transform: scale(1) css property.In Edge it is working as expected when set zoom property to 50% but not working in IE9,10,11

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
body {width: 200%;height: 200%;margin: -50% -50%;}
</style>
```

After adding above print CSS for page, it is working as expected in IE (somewhat better).

For Edge, I added the following code for scaling:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
body {zoom: 50%;}
</style>
```