# How to change default print settings in microsoft edge using css

Tags: css, printing, settings, microsoft-edge

how do you change the default print properties of document in Edge using CSS? The current default print properties has "Shrink-To-Fit" as the default for scale and I would like to change it to 100%. Any ideas how I could do that using css?

Have tried margin:0, padding:0 and changing of height... It is still shrink to it. And the shrink to fit is currently giving the size of 75%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set media="print" and change the zoom attribute.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
   body {
     zoom:100%;
     }
</style>
```

If you define the style sheet in a separate file, you could also use the media attribute when linking to an external style sheet, like:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" media = "print" href = "mystyle.css">
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media#Examples

[print scale to some % like 50% by using CSS for IE9,10,11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949441/print-scale-to-some-like-50-by-using-css-for-ie9-10-11)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried the zoom: 100%. but seems to have made no difference to the printing...
@media print {
  html, body {
    margin:0!important;
    zoom:100%;
  }
}

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've used scale based on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488960/zoom-vs-scale-in-css3